# Python - How do you write a new line in a text file for ever iteration of a while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, io

I am trying to create a log file that captures the output of every iteration of a while loop, however I only seem to be able to capture the penultimate line and a create a blank new line under that.

I have this code:

```
from glob import glob
import task_prep
import time
import datetime

path = glob('F:\\Transcoder\\staging\\prep\\*.xml')


while len(path) >= 0:
    log = open('log_file.txt', 'w')
    if int(len(path)):
        data = (str(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) + ': files')
        print(data)
        log.write(data + '\n')
        task_prep.task_prep()
        path = glob('F:\\Transcoder\\staging\\prep\\*.xml')
        time.sleep(3)

    else:
        data = (str(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) + ': no files')
        print(data)
        log.write(data + '\n')
        path = glob('F:\\Transcoder\\staging\\prep\\*.xml')
        time.sleep(3)
```

This is to just overwrite everything that's being written on the first line, however this is what gets printed:

```
2016-12-06 10:25:56: no files
2016-12-06 10:25:59: no files
2016-12-06 10:26:02: no files
2016-12-06 10:26:05: no files
2016-12-06 10:26:08: no files
2016-12-06 10:26:11: no files
2016-12-06 10:26:14: no files
2016-12-06 10:26:17: no files
2016-12-06 10:26:20: no files
2016-12-06 10:26:23: no files
2016-12-06 10:26:26: no files

Process finished with exit code 1
```

this is what gets written in the text file:

```
2016-12-06 10:26:23: no files
```

A string on line 1 and a new line underneath.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you're printing to a log, you want to open with `'a'`, so it appends output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are opening the file at each loop turn, at the position 0 in the file, hence overwriting the previous result.

You have to open your file before the `while` block to keep the previous position in memory:

```
from glob import glob
import task_prep
import time
import datetime

path = glob('F:\\Transcoder\\staging\\prep\\*.xml')

with open('log_file.txt', 'w') as log:
    while len(path) >= 0:
        if int(len(path)):
            data = (str(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) + ': files')
            log.write(data + '\n')
            task_prep.task_prep()
            path = glob('F:\\Transcoder\\staging\\prep\\*.xml')
            time.sleep(3)

        else:
            data = (str(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) + ': no files')
            log.write(data + '\n')
            path = glob('F:\\Transcoder\\staging\\prep\\*.xml')
            time.sleep(3)
```

**Bonus**: Here, I use `with` which makes the use of the context manager implemented in `open`. The file will automatically be closed after the end of the `with` block.

You could also use the `'a'` mode (for append) but you will still open the file many times which is very inefficient.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing seems to be written when using this method, I just get an empty text file.

Comment: As I have gained more experience with python and with that abetter under standing I have been able to get this concept to work. Thanks!